# Sessão é recriada automaticamente, com um campo dentro

Tags: php, session

Tenho uma classe de Sessões na qual todas as vezes que a instancio ela automaticamente inicia a sessão.

Quando em outro arquivo eu faço eu destruo a sessão através de um método chamado `doLogout` vejo que automaticamente ele apaga a minha sessão como esperado mas cria outra automaticamente sem eu passar nenhum parâmetro.

E essa que é criada automaticamente tem uma entrada chamada *sidebar* de valor `1` que eu não sei de onde vêm, pois em nenhum momento do meu código eu declarei isso.

**Classe**

```
class sessao{
   protected $id_ur;
   protected $nvars;

public function __construct($inicia=true){
    if($inicia==TRUE){
        $this->start();
    }
}
public function start(){
    session_start();
    $this->id_ur = session_id();
    $this->setNvars();
}
private function setNvars(){
    $this->nvars = sizeof($_SESSION);
}
public function getNvars(){
    return $this->nvars;
}
public function setVar($var, $valor){
    $_SESSION[$var] = $valor;
    $this->setNvars();
}
public function unsetVar($var){
    unset($_SESSION[$var]);
    $this->setNvars();
}
public function getVar($var){
    if(isset($_SESSION[$var])){
        return $_SESSION[$var];
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}
public function destroy($inicia=false){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    $this->setNvars();
    if($inicia==TRUE){
        $this->start();
    }

}
public function printAll(){
    foreach ($_SESSION as $k => $v){
        printf("%s = %s<br />", $k, $v);
    }
}
}
?>
```

**Função `doLogout()` mencionada**

```
public function doLogout(){
            $sessao = new sessao();
            $sessao->destroy(TRUE);
            redireciona('index.php');
    }
```

Comment: Sobre você não ter definido esse índice eu duvido. Faça uma busca no seu código-fonte que com certeza vai aparecer. Agora, por acaso, você não instancia essa classe no **index.php** também?

Comment: Sim instancio no index.php por isso é que depois que eu dou o doLogout é que ele volta a classe sessão.

Comment: Bruno Augusto, obrigado pela dica, fui ao meu código fonte, alias eu já tinha ido mas tinha me esquecido de uma pasta onde tinha uns includes e estava lá o erro. vacilo de iniciante. Obrigado ;)

Comment: Resolvido, então?

Comment: Sim, resolvido, obrigado pela dica ;)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para que o tópico não fique sem uma resposta propriamente dita:

Se existe uma entrada em $_SESSION, é porque uma variável de sessão foi criada em algum momento do código. Se você não se lembra, faça uma busca em todos seus códigos-fonte. Alguns editores ou mesmo IDEs inteiras já conta com esse tipo recurso de recurso.

Atente para o fato de sua classe não finalizar a gravação dos dados de sessão. O mecanismo de sessões do PHP é preguiçoso e só grava as adições  feitas no "último segundo".

Se um redirecionamento é feito antes do PHP "reagir" e gravar os dados, você perderá os dados.

Para forçar a gravação dos dados, invoque [session_write_close()](http://www.php.net/session_write_close) em algum momento do seu código mas **antes** que um redirecionamento ocorra, seja manualmente, seja num método da classe.